# Standard libraries of LLVM C++ and GNU C++ have different headers

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, gnu, std

I have to use `unordered_map` and `trie`, but not one standard library, nor another one contains both of them.

```
// works only with LLVM library
#include <unordered_map>
// works only with GNU library
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
```

I mean which is described on the [GCC GNU website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/trie_based_containers.html).

The program is building in Xcode 7.2.1. I have tried to use GNU C++14, GNU C++11 and C++14, C++11, but it doesn't help.

How this problem may be solved? Probably, my GNU library is too old, can I update it in Xcode? Or, maybe, LLVM has `assoc_container.hpp` is some other path?

Comment: You might want to update your GNU stdlibc++. You can use macports or homebrew for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation of [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is a requirement for C++11.   This suggests you are using an older version of `stdlibc++`.

If you're stuck with that version, Boost provides an [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) that you could use.

You can't expect libc++ (Clang's C++ library) to have GNU extensions.  You can, however, mix and match `libstc++` and `libc++` in the same executable (but not compilation unit) due to the latter's use of inline namespaces, which mean that its symbols won't clash with the former.

Edit:

Seems the OP is compiling on MacOSX using a recent version of clang.

In this case, the `libstd++` shipping with the toolchain is a creaking old version without C++11 support.  It is deprecated as far as Apple is concerned.

The best bet is to either: modify code to avoid use of extensions in `libstdc++` - which in any case appear to C++11 pre-release features
or: build with both libraries (yes, this is totally possible on MacOSX and iOS). Caveat here is that you can only ever use one or the other in any compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) came in with the C++11 standard, and not all compilers use C++11 (or later) as standard yet meaning you have to add flags when building to be able to use it.

When building with GCC versions prior to 5.1 you should add the flag `-std=c++11` (or optionally `-std=gnu++11` if you want GCC extensions, or `-std=c++0x` if you have a really old version of GCC).

Comment: @AivanF. Then please edit your question to show us how you build your program, what flags you have, what IDE project settings you have.

Comment: Please run `gcc --version` so that we can see what you've got.  Same options work for clang.

Comment: @marko it says: Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 Thread model: posix

Comment: `gcc` on OS X is a symlink to `clang`

Comment: ok. You're using MacOSX.  If you're using the libstdc++, this is stuck at an older version that doesn't support C++11- I believe for licensing reasons.

libstdc++ is deprecated as far as Apple is concerned for use on MacOSX.